# asp.net core 2.0 identity entity framework user not saved

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am trying to implement basic authentication in my application. The users should be stored in a postgresql database.

I am able to create a user but I have no idea where it is stored. It is not stored in my database. But all created users are stored and accessible from the `UserManager`. After a reboot the created users are still there. So it isn't stored in my database or in memory.

I used this part to enable identity with entity framework.

```
services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DatabaseContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

The `User` and `Role` classes are just extending from `IdentityUser` and `IdentityRole` with `Guid` as key type.

I use `npgsql` for the database. I am pretty sure it is working because the migrations are migrated correctly:

```
var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseContext");
services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()
    .AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(connectionString));
```

For creating and getting users I inject `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager<User>` in the controller.

Why are the users not stored in my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UserManager<TUser>` will look for an injected `IUserStore<TUser>`. That's how it persists users and chats with your database. The default implementation of the user store [can be found here.](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/UserStore.cs) By default, this implementation looks to inject `DbContext` directly.

Thing's I'd try:

- Make sure your database context inherits from `IdentityDbContext`
- Request a `IUserStore` from your service collection and look at the `Context` property to see what database context it's using.

If you're absolutely sure that your users are not going into your database, then `IUserStore<TUser>` must be using a different context to the one you're using. If that's the case, either delete the other context or add a more specific version of `IUserStore` to your service collection. Ex: Replace `IUserStore<TUser>` in your services  with `UserStore<TUser, IdentityRole, DatabaseContext, string>`. (Note that we're specifying `DatabaseContext` there, instead of the base class `DbContext`)

Comment: The problem was that my database context inherit from `DBContext`... I changed it to `IdentityDbContext` and it worked.